# How to solve Reverse for 'all_worker' with keyword arguments '{'Slug': 'elctric'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['jobs/(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$']

Tags: python, django

i have two models(category&Worker)and i show all category at home page , when press in any category i need to get all workers that belong to this category but i get this error at the top

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.text import slugify 
from django.urls import reverse

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField( max_length=40) 
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='category_img')
    Slug = models.SlugField(blank = True , null = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
    def save(self , *args  ,**kwargs ):
        self.Slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Category , self).save( *args , **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('jobs:all_worker', kwargs={'Slug': self.Slug})
    
class Worker(models.Model):
    job = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='worker_img')
    place = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Slug = models.SlugField(blank = True , null = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    def save(self , *args  ,**kwargs ):
        self.Slug = slugify(self.job)
        super(Worker , self).save( *args , **kwargs)
```

views.py

```
def all_worker(request,slug):
    workers = get_object_or_404(Worker,slug=slug)
    return render(request, 'jobCategory/worker_list.html', {'workers':workers})
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.category, name='category'),
    path('<slug:slug>', views.all_worker, name='all_worker'),

]
```

template

```
        {% for category in categories %}
            <div class="col border shadow-lg p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded m-2">                   
            <a href="{{category.get_absolute_url}}">
              <img src="{{category.img.url}}" height="200px" width="200px">
              <p class="text-center font-weight-bold text-info mt-3">{{category}}</p>
            </a>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Note that field names should not be capitalised

Comment: It should be `{'slug': ...}` instead of `{ 'Slug': }`...

Comment: its really worked, thank you very match

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove the second slug in your urls.py